# how is it possible to configure uwsgi in emperor-mode with cgi-plugin + heartbeat in combination with nginx

Tags: nginx, cgi, uwsgi

After having the migration from fcgiwrap to uWSGI (which also brings plenty of other benefits that I'm planning to use) on my ToDo-list for some time I finally managed to setup a debian-wheezy test-system featuring uWSGI v2.0 and nginx v1.4.4.

In the first step I would like to run .cgi-scripts through [uWSGI's cgi-plugin](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html) reliably and with minimal overhead (rather weak hardware below) while having the option to easily enhance my configuration to also deploy apps through frameworks such as bottle/flask/django as a second step.

Therefore I chose to make use of [uWSGI's emperor mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html), which is currently set up to control only one vassal which is configured to run the uWSGI-cgi-plugin on 2 workers with 2 threads each.

After checking out various features the setup is more or less running ok now with 2 weird behaviours that I think are somehow **wrong**:

- As soon as the vassal is configured to send heartbeats to the emperor (e.g. through adding `heartbeat = 20` to the .ini), the emperor will repeatedly kill/respawn the vassal's master if the .cgi has not been run within the defined heartbeat-timespan. *the number of workers configured doesn't seem to matter here.*
- The vassal ignores the option `reload-mercy = 10` as it still logs `your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds` (which is the default-value). *ok, this is just a minor issue and of no big relevance to me.*

The reason for using the heartbeat-option is that i would like to assure the availability of my cgis/apps by using the built-in uWSGI mechanisms as good as possible.

Any hints what i might be misunderstanding or doing wrong?
I can't see any apparent reason why it should not be possible to use the heartbeat option in combination with the cgi-module in my configuration but would be grateful for any further insight!
I assume nginx has nothing to do with the mentioned issues plus I also double-checked file and directory-perms...
uWSGI is started through an init.d-script but the behaviour is the same when starting manually.

My **configuration** is as follows:

- section in nginx.conf:

  ```
  location ~ ^/cgi-bin/.*\..+$ {
     root            /usr/local/nginx/vhosts/testdomain.com/cgi-bin;
     gzip            off;
     include         uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_modifier1 9;
     uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/run/nginx/testdomain_cgi-bin_uwsgi.sock;
   }
  ```
- emperor.ini:

  ```
  [uwsgi]
  uid = www-data
  gid = www-data
  emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
  emperor-pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/emperor.pid
  daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi_emperor.log
  ```
- testdomain_cgi-bin.ini:

  ```
  [uwsgi]
  uid = www-data
  gid = www-data
  chdir = /usr/local/nginx/vhosts/testdomain/cgi-bin
  plugins = cgi
  cgi = /cgi-bin=/usr/local/nginx/vhosts/testdomain/cgi-bin
  cgi-allowed-ext = .cgi
  socket = /var/run/nginx/testdomain_cgi-bin_uwsgi.sock
  master = true
  #heartbeat = 25
  processes = 2
  threads = 2
  reload-mercy = 10
  no-orphans = true
  post-buffering = 4096
  max-requests = 2048
  vacuum = true
  logto = /usr/local/nginx/logs/uwsgi_testdomain_cgi-bin.log
  ```

**logs** (when option heartbeat is enabled):

- /var/log/uwsgi_emperor.log:

  ```
  *** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (32bit) on [Wed Feb  5 11:35:36 2014] ***
  compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 31 January 2014 08:46:00
  os: Linux-3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1
  nodename: testnode
  machine: i686
  clock source: unix
  pcre jit disabled
  detected number of CPU cores: 1
  current working directory: /
  *** running under screen session 1111.myscrn ***
  detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  setgid() to 33
  setuid() to 33
  *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
  your processes number limit is 3940
  your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  writing pidfile to /var/run/uwsgi/emperor.pid
  *** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
  *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
  [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from testdomain_cgi-bin.ini
  Wed Feb  5 11:35:36 2014 - [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini has been spawned
  Wed Feb  5 11:35:36 2014 - [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini is ready to accept requests
  Wed Feb  5 11:35:43 2014 - [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini is now loyal
  [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini sent no heartbeat in last 30 seconds, brutally respawning it...
  Wed Feb  5 11:38:56 2014 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance testdomain_cgi-bin.ini
  [emperor] unrecognized vassal event on fd 5
  [emperor] unrecognized vassal event on fd 5
      ... above lines repeaded for about another 50 times ... 
  *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
  [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from testdomain_cgi-bin.ini
  Wed Feb  5 11:38:56 2014 - [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini has been spawned
  Wed Feb  5 11:38:56 2014 - [emperor] vassal testdomain_cgi-bin.ini is ready to accept requests
  ```
- /usr/local/nginx/logs/uwsgi_testdomain_cgi-bin.log:

  ```
  *** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (32bit) on [Wed Feb  5 11:35:36 2014] ***
  compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 31 January 2014 08:46:00
  os: Linux-3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1
  nodename: testnode
  machine: i686
  clock source: unix
  pcre jit disabled
  detected number of CPU cores: 1
  current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
  *** running under screen session 1111.myscrn ***
  detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  your processes number limit is 3940
  your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
  thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
  uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/nginx/testdomain_cgi-bin_uwsgi.sock fd 3
  your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
  your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
  mapped 175536 bytes (171 KB) for 2 cores
  *** Operational MODE: threaded ***
  initialized CGI mountpoint: /cgi-bin = /usr/local/nginx/vhosts/testdomain.com/cgi-bin
  *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
  *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
  spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 20825)
  spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20826, cores: 2)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/1] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:35:43 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 13 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/2] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:35:54 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/3] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:36:04 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/4] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:36:16 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/5] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:36:28 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/6] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:36:39 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/7] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:36:51 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/8] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:37:03 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/9] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:37:15 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/10] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:37:27 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/11] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:37:39 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 12 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/12] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:37:51 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 1)
  [pid: 20826|app: -1|req: -1/13] XX.XX.XX.XXX () {42 vars in 678 bytes} [Wed Feb  5 11:38:03 2014] GET /cgi-bin/hellow.cgi => generated 282 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
  Wed Feb  5 11:38:56 2014 - uWSGI worker 1 screams: UAAAAAAH my master disconnected: i will kill myself !!!
  *** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (32bit) on [Wed Feb  5 11:38:56 2014] ***
  compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 31 January 2014 08:46:00
  os: Linux-3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1
  nodename: testnode
  machine: i686
  clock source: unix
  pcre jit disabled
  detected number of CPU cores: 1
  current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
  *** running under screen session 1111.myscrn ***
  detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  your processes number limit is 3940
  your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
  thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
  uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/nginx/testdomain_cgi-bin_uwsgi.sock fd 3
  your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
  your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
  mapped 175536 bytes (171 KB) for 2 cores
  *** Operational MODE: threaded ***
  initialized CGI mountpoint: /cgi-bin = /usr/local/nginx/vhosts/testdomain.com/cgi-bin
  *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
  *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
  spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 20881)
  spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20882, cores: 2)
  ```

**uWSGI doc** for the vassal option `heartbeat`:

```
    Argument: number

    (Vassal option) Announce vassal health to the emperor every N seconds.
```

**uWSGI doc** for the emperor option `emperor-required-heartbeat`:

```
    Argument: number Default: 30

    Set the Emperor tolerance about heartbeats.

    When a vassal asks for ‘heartbeat mode’ the emperor will 
    also expect a ‘heartbeat’ at least every <secs> seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2.0.1 from github, it has better heartbeat code. Your problem is the little timedelta between emperor tolerance (30 seconds) and heartbeat frequency (25). For a bug in 2.0 the worker timeout got reset at every request. In addition to this 2.0.1 heartbeat is triggered as soon as the first worker is spawned leading to better results (broken apps are immediately detected). Regarding worker reload mercy, the right option is `--worker-reload-mercy` (`--reload-mercy` is for non-worker processes)

Comment: thanks for the just-in-time-fix =)
works now smoothly as expected!
`worker-reload-mercy` option seems undocumented up to now but does the right thing; so would `reload-mercy` therefore only affect masters (or what other non-worker-processes are there)?

Comment: oh and the [option-doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#reload-mercy) for `reload-mercy` needs an overhaul as it explicitly mentions `Set the maximum time (in seconds) a worker can take to reload/shutdown` ... which might be ... rather misleading? ;)